# Circular shape with sine edge

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am looking for a method to create a circular shape that has a sine wave as an edge. Like the picture I posted in addition to this question. I want the edge to be a sine wave and the rest of the surface to be warped.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the inner face be additionally subdivided and have a smooth gradient inward, or do you mean it exactly as @Chris depicted in his answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a lazy version, that starts with a bottomless, 0-height cone:

[image]

.it gives you the option of an n-gon at the center:

[image]

.. if you wanted, you could raise or lower the center, too, for a more or less conical profile.

[image]

Comment: This one's just to get a G&T from [quellenform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282052/35559), really.. I've learned a lot more from his version :)

Comment: What's a "G&T"? You young people and your abbreviations...

Comment: It's a Gin and Tonic at the 19th hole for a rare win (IMHO) at a round of Node Golf.. :)

Comment: I like that! Cheers! (...by the way, my first attempt was also with a cylinder, which has a better distribution of indices, but I personally did not like the innermost face)

Comment: @quellenform... OK, that would be 'Inner Radius' 0. I think the cone merges automatically...  :P ...  But Hey, it's Christmas. My round at the bar. You're the pro :)

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed! You never stop learning ;-)

Answer (score 9):

> I assume that you need not only the outer edge, but also a nice topology inside the shape.

[image]

Maybe this example will help you:

[image]

As basis I use here a mesh, which I created from two curves with `Curve to Mesh`.

This has the advantage that I can divide it on two axes into as many segments as I want.

With a few math nodes I capture the points concentrically and radially and can move their positions accordingly.

So that the flow of the mesh remains adjustable also to the center, I use here additionally the node `Float Curve`.

The advantage of this solution is that it creates a mesh that is built up with quads, so you can additionally apply a subdivision.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Hey it's me again. Thank you very much for your suggestion. Is there a way to angle the outer edge towards the center? For example that the face discribing sine wave runns on the surface of a imaginary cone.

Comment: @Alec Sorry for the late reply. I'm afraid I don't understand exactly what you mean or how it should look. Can you please sketch it with an image?

Comment: @Alec Was that an accident that you deselected the previously accepted answer? Would you have had a few more questions about it?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this node setup here:

[image]

Note: i did not search for a formula for the integer value so that it "fits". I just tried out and 151 fitted  ;)

result:

[image]

--- update

solution for z - axis:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice thank you. Can you help me realizing this pattern not in the x and y (radial) scale but in the z axis?

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped alot.

Comment: pls click on the checkmark left of my answer, if it helped you. thx