# How to "displace" a curve in geometry nodes following a math formula

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I am trying to make curve and then displace it, I have seen this achieved by using the noise texture and the set position nodes. but in this case I want to take a curve input and then displace it in a sinusoidal wave along its tangent, being able to control frecency and amplitude. For some reason all i am able to get is for it to get displaced in the global X or Y but not normal to the tangent.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you post images of what you have tried? And maybe draw something of about the expected output?

Comment: checkout this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282040/circular-shape-with-sine-edge it should help you

Answer (score 2):

There's no single vector normal to the tangent of a curve .. so we can let that be determined by the curve's *Tilt*.

Here's a group that will deform a given curve, perpendicular to its tangent, as a sinusoidal function of its length:

[image]

.. allowing you to set frequency, phase, amplitude, and a (Y) shift of the sin function (in X), along with the tilt , so you can choose your normal.

[image]

[image]

Varying the tilt along the curve would require a few more nodes, and a decision about what kind of interface you'd like, to that parameter.